# Unable to create a table using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have not much exposure to jQuery plug-ins. I am trying to create a dataTable grid. However, the data does not load in table. All the cells get 'undefined' values.Kindly advise .Thanks you.  Below are the sample configurations:

```
function createModelTable(){
        var htmlTable = '';
        for(var i = 1; i <= line; i++){
            var htmlTr = '';
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                htmlTr = '<tr class="bgcolor">';
            }else{
                htmlTr = '<tr>';
            }
            for(var j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
                var index = line * j + i;
                index = pad(index, 3);
                if( lotIds.indexOf(gameType) > -1 && index > 97 ){
                    index = '';
                }

                if ((gameType == 3 && index > 23) || (gameType == 10 && index > 82)
                    || (gameType == 11 && index > 80) || (gameType == 16 && index > 79)) {
                    htmlTr += '<td></td>';
                } else {
                    htmlTr += '<td><span class="text1">' + index + '</span><span class="open_num" id="draw_td_' + index + '"></span></td>';
                }
            }
            htmlTr += '</tr>';
            htmlTable += htmlTr;
        }
        $('#cqssc_draw_list_tbody').html(htmlTable);
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="sl-draw-list">
                <div class="sl-draw-list-t">
                    <span class="sl-draw-list-t-red"><span id="search_result_day"><?php echo $date;?></span> 开奖号码</span>
                    <ul id="sl_draw_list_t_tab" class="sl-draw-list-t-tab">
                        <li class="active" date="<?php echo $date;?>"><a href="javascript:;">今天</a></li>
                        <li date="<?php echo $yes;?>"><a href="javascript:;">昨天</a></li>
                        <li date="<?php echo $bef;?>"><a href="javascript:;">前天</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="sl-draw-list-t-date">
                        按日期查询：<input type="text" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" id="cqssc_draw_time_box" class="cqssc-draw-time-box">
                        <input type="hidden" id="lottery-id" value="<?php echo $output['id'];?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sl-draw-list-table-out">
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="winning-lottery-table ssq-lottery-table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="33.3%"><span class="text1">期号</span><span class="text2">开奖号</span></th>
                            <th width="33.3%"><span class="text1">期号</span><span class="text2">开奖号</span></th>
                            <th><span class="text1">期号</span><span class="text2">开奖号</span> </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="cqssc_draw_list_tbody"></tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: ajax? there is none. what about console errors? what errors do you get

Comment: @JaromandaX i get undefined value from for(var i = 1; i <= line; i++){

Comment: Looks like th 'line' variable isn't defined.

Comment: `line` is not defined in the code you posted ... there are many more vars that are used with no obvious definition

Comment: you've tagged this question [tag:ajax] and have used the word ajax in the question - but there is no evidence of ajax in the code ... I know what you're doing wrong. You are calling `createModelTable` before the asynchronous ajax call has completed, therefore the vars you think will have useful values actually wont